# Poetry add or update is throwing authorization errors

Tags: python-poetry

I have a Poetry `pyproject.toml` that looks something like this:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "classifier"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["John Doe"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.10,<3.12.0"
torch = { version = "2.0.0", source = "torch" }
torchvision = { version = "0.15.1", source = "torch" }
fvcore = "^0.1.5.post20221221"
accelerate = "^0.17.1"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "pypi-mirror"
url = "http://pypi-cache.privaterepo.com/root/pypi/+simple"
default = true

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "torch"
url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118"
secondary = true

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
black = "^23.3.0"
isort = "^5.12.0"
flake8 = "^6.0.0"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

When I try to run `poetry add X` or `poetry update`, I get a series of Authorization errors that look like this:

```
Resolving dependencies... (1.1s)Source (torch): Authorization error accessing https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118/[insert-package-name]
```

That same line is printed multiple times, each with a different library name at the end. After going through all of that, it starts to install PyTorch normally.

What is the problem here? Am I setting the source incorrectly?